# how do you increment a variable in an insert by picking the last id from another table at each row?

Tags: insert, mariadb

Statement mysql / mariadb:

`max(so_id) 1`: obviously always returns the same number incremented the first time!

```
INSERT INTO sottoc
   (so_idgru, so_idconto, so_id, so_code, so_name)
(SELECT cust_idgru, cust_idconto, 
        (SELECT max(so_id)+1
         FROM sottoc
         WHERE so_idgru=cust_idgru AND so_idconto=cust_idconto),
        cust_code, cust_name 
 FROM customer);
```

table `customer`:

```
cust_code   cust_idgru  cust_idconto
001             2               2
002             5               3
```

table `sottoc`:

```
so_code     so_idgru        so_idconto  so_id
```

existing values:

```
010             2               2               1
023             5               3               7
```

add record from customer it should come:

```
001             2               2               2   
002             5               3               8
```

---

edit 22 ago 2018 - 14:50

ok. Thanks for the answers and sorry if I was unclear.

I try to explain myself in more detail:

'customer' table, 3 fields and 2 records:

`cust_code   cust_idgru  cust_idconto
001             2               2
002             5               3`

'sottoc' table, 4 fields and 10 records : 

`so_code     so_idgru        so_idconto      so_id
010             2               2               1
012             2               2               2
015             2               2               3
023             5               3               1
027             5               3               2
030             5               3               3
023             5               3               4
023             5               3               5
023             5               3               6
023             5               3               7`

The primary key of 'sottoc' is composed of so_idgru+so_idconto+so_id and that so_id is progressive within the partial key so_id_gru+so_idconto

(I know it would have been better id progressive single, but this has been passed to me and on this I must to work!)

As shown in the example 2-2-1, 2-2-2, ... 5-3-1, 5-3-2, ...

so_id CAN NOT be renumbered because it is related to other tables!

I have to add the 2 'customer' records in order to have the 'sottoc' table :

`so_code     so_idgru        so_idconto      so_id
010             2               2               1
012             2               2               2
001             2               2               3    <--- 
015             2               2               3
023             5               3               1
027             5               3               2
030             5               3               3
023             5               3               4
023             5               3               5
023             5               3               6
023             5               3               7
002             5               3               8   <---`

Thanks

Enrico

---

For now I used this way:

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE cursor_idgru INT;
    DECLARE cursor_idconto INT;
    DECLARE cursor_code VARCHAR(50);
    -- cursor for distinct cust_idgru+cust_idconto
    DECLARE cursor_i CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT cust_idgru, cust_idconto
            FROM customer 

            GROUP BY cust_idgru, cust_idconto;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
    -- cursor loop
    OPEN cursor_i;
    read_loop: LOOP
        FETCH cursor_i INTO cursor_idgruppo, cursor_idconto;
        IF done THEN
            LEAVE read_loop;
        END IF;
        -- last so_id of the cursor_idgru/cursor_idconto
        SET @uidsottoc = (SELECT max(so_id) FROM sottoc WHERE so_idgru=cursor_idgru AND so_idconto=cursor_idconto);
        IF(@uidsottoc IS NULL) THEN
            SET @uidsottoc := 0;
        END IF;
        INSERT INTO sottoc
            (so_idgru, so_idconto, so_id, so_code, so_name)
             (SELECT cust_idgru, cust_idconto, @uidsottoc := @uidsottoc + 1, cust_code, cust_name
                FROM customer
                WHERE cust_idgru=cursor_idgru AND cust_idconto=cursor_idconto);
        COMMIT;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE cursor_i;
END
```

thank you all

Enrico

Comment: This question is not answerable.  You gave no description, and also I don't see input _and_ output data, so I can't piece together your logic by seeing your data.  Please fix your question.

Comment: In addition to what Tim said if you are trying to manually determine a value from another column you will likely run into a race condition at some point. Please describe more clearly what the problem is that you are trying to solve.